# The best practice to do operations on two tables from one controller Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I wonder if it's a bad practice to use two models in one controller.

I have two tables: sold and warehouse.

Warehouse contains items that are available for sale and the quantity, for example "Keyboard XYZ" Quantity: 195

Sold contains orders from customers, for example Buyer: John Smith, Product: Keyboard XYZ

My problem is that in one function in SoldController where I add a new order to sold table, I also need to subtract quantity from warehouse table.

What is the best way to do it?

I read that calling a function subtractQuantity from WarehouseController in SoldController would be bad practice -
**WarehouseController::subtractQuantity($id)** in SoldController function (calling a function from one controller from another controller)

Should I use WarehouseModel in SoldController? (so basically use two Models in one controller)

Use Traits? (not too familiar with those yet)

Comment: why you want to call another controller inside controller, just use as many model you want in your controller and deal with different tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a separate service class that deals with this cross cutting concerns in your business logic and inject that service into you `SoldController`.

The service, call it `SalesService`, will then be implementing the actual sales, whether it will be adding the record into `sold` table and subtracting the quantity from the warehouse.

Comment: Oh thank you, I'm quite new to Laravel and back-end overall. But now that I read about the purpose of a service class, I think it's what I need here.

Answer (score 1):

Use both models in your controller:

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Sold;
use App\Warehouse;

class SoldController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
      $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function insert()
    {
        $sold = new Sold;
        $sold->field_one = $request->field_one;
        $sold->field_two = $request->field_two;
        $sold->save();

        $warehouseItem = Warehouse::find($some_id);
        //and do the rest
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if it's okay to use multiple models in one controller.